# Error in paste("sub", j, sep = "")[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I would like to create a loop that can loop through (sub1[1,] ... sub1[1200,]) ... (sub10[1,] ... sub10[1200,])

```
for (j in 1:10){

        entries=1:1200
        for (i in 1:1200){
    entries[i]=max(table(sort(unlist(paste("sub",j,sep="")[i,]))-1:3)) > 2
}
        nam=paste("newsub",j,sep="")
        assign(nam, paste("sub",j,sep="")[!entries,])

}
```

however, I keep getting the error "Error in paste("sub", j, sep = "")[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions".

I think I have apply a function to a string, but I have already used the paste() function; how can I fix this?

*edit:
I expect to have sub1[i,]...sub10[i,], where j=1:10

Comment: `unlist(paste("sub",j,sep="")` will return a vector, a vector does not have dimension you would might need `unlist(paste("sub",j,sep="")[i]`. But do you actually need `unlist` here? Can you give a reproducible example and show expected output?

Comment: @markus Hi, I basically want to do the same thing as what shown in this website https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/axv7c2/remove_combinations_that_have_series_of_numbers/
the only difference is that I have 10 groups and 1200 rows. (so I adapt the codes from there)

Comment: What are `sub1` and `sub10`? Please include a minimal working example and show the expected output. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for a guidance.

Comment: @markus Oh, sub[j] is just a data.frame of ( row=1200, col=7 ) of random combinations. For example, sub1 = 1 2 3 4 6 89 321

I will try to include a working example later, thanks!

Comment: The error message says it all. I don't think the `paste( ...) [ , ]` makes sense. There's no defined dimensioned value returned for `paste` so indexing it seems "just wrong". Close vote for no [MCVE]